# Error: NG0302: The pipe 'translate' could not be found! when importing another component

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have **report.component.ts** which I am trying to import into **test.component.ts**
Before the import **test.component** works (even translations), but when I import **report.component** this error message pops up: **Error: NG0302: The pipe 'translate' could not be found!**

What am I missing?

**test.component.ts**

```
import {ReportComponent} from "../report/report.component";
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'test-root',
  styleUrls: ['test.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService){}

  @ViewChild(ReportComponent) report: ReportComponent;
```

**test.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {SharedService} from '../common/shared.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatTableModule} from "@angular/material/table";
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../app-routing.module';
import {TestComponent} from "./test.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    TestComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    [SharedService]
    // Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [ TestComponent ],
  exports: [TestComponent, TranslateModule]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

**report.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { ReportComponent } from './report.component';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {SharedService} from '../common/shared.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {TestModule} from "../Test/test.module";
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../app-routing.module';
import {MinimenuModule} from '../minimenu/minimenu.module';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {TestComponent} from "../Test/test.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MinimenuModule,
    TestModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReportComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    [SharedService]
    // Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [ ReportComponent ],
  exports: [ReportComponent, TranslateModule]
})
export class ReportModule { }
```

Comment: UPDATE: although workaround -  opting out of Ivy "enableIvy": false, in tsconfig.json seems to help

Comment: How are you importing the `TranslateModule` within your AppModule?